# Prevent setinterval() from reset on every page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, setinterval

I am creating one Web Application in `C# MVC` and i want one features for play beep at every time interval which i have defined in variable.

> I'm using `setInterval()` function of javascript in layout page but it
>   is called  on every page load and inverval is reseting.

I have tried some solution but still can't get any solution.

Comment: You can't do this without hacks, you need different kind of technologies, e.g. SPA (Single Page Application). C# MVC is not good fot this.

Comment: @hawk, with due respect, that's quite an opinionated comment, when there is enough documentation on how to build SPAs using ASP.NET MVC and C#. For instance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/single-page-application/overview/.

Comment: thanks for reply.i have already created on POS system in C# MVC and in same system I want to create above feature.

Comment: @sudheeshix true, i think you misunderstood me. I said C# MVC can't be used as SPA alone, of course you need something link React, Angular, Knockout, Ember etc. For backend part I think C# WebAPI is more than enough. But this is another story, Regards.

Comment: @hawk, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid page reloads if you have subsequent requests (after the initial page load) return partial pages (html) or data (typically json). This can then be rendered on the page quite simply using AJAX, or if you feel inclined to, by using a JavaScript framework such as Angular to build a Single Page Application.

With ASP.NET MVC, you can explore sending back **JsonResult** from the controller actions instead of ViewResult.